# Aligning two lists with duplicate keys

Tags: python, list, alignment

This question is similar to "Aligning to Lists in python" question, but I have a problem with using a dictionary because of repeated numbers for potential keys.

Here is an example. Start with these 2 lists:

If I used a dictionary these would be the keys. [5,6,6,1,6,1,6,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1]

[13,14,15,10,16,11,17,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,16,17]

I am able to rearrange the first list the way I want it, which is:

[5,6,6,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1]

I want the second list to keep it's same alignment, to the first list and look exactly like this:
[13,14,15,16,17,10,11,12,12,13,14,13,14,15,16,17]

Notice that it matters that the list of potential keys has it's repeated values aligned by position with the corresponding values in the second list.

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for a python [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). Have you considered using a single `list` of 2-item `tuples`? That way when you rearrange by the first item in each `tuple`, your `list` will maintain the correct order for all of the second items.

Comment: What relationship have the lists got with  a dictionary? I don't quite understand what you are asking

Comment: I think the notion of a dictionary is how the OP wants to conceptualize the coupling of the two lists. The problem is that a dictionary can't have repeating keys, so in practice it wouldn't work. I believe the OP is asking how to create such a hypothetical mapping, and then have that be preserved upon rearranging of the keys.

Comment: One of the issues with what the OP is trying to do is that it can lead to ambiguous results. How do we know which key in the final list was originally in the first list? If there isn't a one-to-one relationship there, then it's impossible to know which of the second-list items should have been moved around where. Using a tuple could solve this because it creates that one-to-one relationship for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other people below your post, I don't completely understand your problem (could you be more specific about relation you want to obtain?), but maybe `zip` is the answer for your question:

```
>>> a = [5,6,6,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1]
>>> b = [13,14,15,16,17,10,11,12,12,13,14,13,14,15,16,17]
>>> alignment = zip(a, b)
>>> alignment
[(5, 13), (6, 14), (6, 15), (6, 16), (6, 17), (1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (1, 12), (1, 13), (1, 14), (2, 13), (2, 14), (2, 15), (2, 16), (1, 17)]
```

**Edited**:

```
key_list = [5,6,6,1,6,1,6,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1]
values_list = [13,14,15,10,16,11,17,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,16,17]
zipped_lists = zip(key_list, values_list)
sorted_zip = sorted(zipped_lists)
pattern = [5,6,6,6,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1]
temp_dict = {}
for key, value in sorted_zip:
    if key not in temp_dict:
        temp_dict[key] = [value]
    else:
        temp_dict[key].append(value)

final_list = []
for i in pattern:
    final_list.append((i, temp_dict[i].pop(0)))
```

And, of course, final_list is your result.

Comment: Thanks,you have the idea of where I'm trying to get with this, and why the dictionary idea didn't work, but I don't actually have the list you named b, not in that order. I only have the other 3 lists. So if I zip the first 2 lists together, how can I use my 3rd list to get them rearranged like your zipped list?

Comment: @AnneIzy Check this edit, if I understood you well, it will be solution. I assumed, that in group of keys (and by group I mean 1 and its values, 2 and its values, 5... etc.) values are in some way monotonic. I'm not sure is this is what you actually wont, but it works for this case.

Comment: By the way, this was a really nice problem actually. I don't know if this is optimal solution for problems of that type, but with my current algorithmic skills I cannot find any better.

Comment: Very cool! Thank you so much!  I get everything except I'm curious if it would still work without the sorted function?

Comment: In this special case - yes, because all pairs in zipped list restricted to the group of pairs with same first element ((1,x), (1,y)... for example) are already sorted in lexicographical order. But if some of them would be mixed the result wouldn't be correct. It's just more general, safer solution. :)
If you don't want to use `sorted()` function, comment the line with it and change `sorted_zip` to `zipped_lists` in first for-loop.